# Uploading file from form to server

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, http

I am currently working on a dashboard, and have been stuck for some couple of hours now... What I like to do is to have a form including 3 `<input type="file">` (two of them allow multiple files, one not), and each of them posting to 3 different post-methods in the server. When I try to console log the request on the server side the data is empty ({}) . I do not understand why, can someone please help me solve this issue?

I am using angularjs, and nodejs btw.

This is what my current code is : (files and paths are dummy-names)

## HTML:

```
 <form role="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="file1">File1:</label> 
            <input type="file" id="file1" accept=".txt, .json" multiple> 
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="file2">File2:</label> 
            <input type="file" id="file2" accept=".json"> 
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="file3">File3:</label>
            <input type="file" id="file3" multiple> 
        </div>
        <button type="button" ng-click="save()" class="btn btn-default"> Save</button>
    </form>
```

## JS:

```
module.exports = function($scope, $http) {
        $scope.save = function () {
              file1(document.getElementById('file1').files);
              file2(document.getElementById('file2').files);
              file3(document.getElementById('file3').files);
        };

        function file1(files) { 
            $http.post('/file1', {f: files}).success(function (res) {
               //todo
            });
        };

        function file2(files) { 
            $http.post('/file2', {f: files}).success(function (res) {
              //todo
            });
        };

        function file3(files) { 
            $http.post('/file3', {f: files}).success(function (res) {
              //todo
            });
        };
 }
```

## Server.js

```
var express = require("express"),
    fs = require("fs"),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser'),

    app.use(express.static("build"));
    app.use(bodyParser());

    app.post('/file1', function (req, res) {
       console.log(req.body.f) // returns empty: {} 
       // like to move files to path: a/b/c
    });

    app.post('/file2', function (req, res) {
       // like to move files to path: a/d/e
    });

    app.post('/file3', function (req, res) {
      // like to move files to path: a/f/g
    });
```

## Update:

after receiving the answer from [GrimurD](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1470747/grimurd), I have modified the server.js, but still struggling. Any takers?

```
var express = require("express"),
        fs = require("fs"),
        bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
        multer = require('multer'), //<-- updated
        upload =  multer({ dest: './uploads/' }) //<-- updated

    app.use(express.static("build"));
    app.use(bodyParser());
    app.use(multer({ dest: './uploads/' }).array()); // <-- updated

    app.post('/file1', upload.array('file1'), function (req, res) {
       console.log(req.body.f) // returns empty: {} 
       console.log(req.files); // returns undefined // <-- updated
       // like to move files to path: a/b/c
    });

    app.post('/file2', upload.single('file2'), function (req, res) {
       console.log(req.file); // returns undefined  // <-- updated
       // like to move files to path: a/d/e
    });

    app.post('/file3', upload.array('file3'), function (req, res) {
      console.log(req.files); // returns undefined // <-- updated
      // like to move files to path: a/f/g
    });
```

Comment: I dont know much about angularjs or node.js but from my experience in PHP, I can say if we want to upload a file we must give enctype attribure to the form like <form role="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">

Answer (score 0):

When uploading a file the form must use multipart/form-data which body-parser doesn't support. You must use a specialized middleware to handle this type. [Multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer) is one such that I have used with success.

Answer (score 0):

You can get around this using FileReader.readAsDataURL(..) on the File objects in the input fields. I often like to use the multi-select ability on the file input type so that I can upload a bunch of files and do this async.

So what I normally do is access the files property on the input element and loop through them, then I use the [FileReader.readAsDataURL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL) to get the base64 of the binary for the files then passing the base64 to a webserivce method with a signature that accepts that a string param for the base64, convert the b64 to binary and you're back in business.

```js
var fileRunner = {
  files: [],
  run: function(el) {
    this.files = el.files;
    this.read();
  },
  read: function() {

    // begin the read operation
    console.log(this.files.length);
    for (var i = 0; i <= this.files.length - 1; i++) {
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[i]);
      reader.onload = this.process
    }

  },
  process: function(evt) {
    var result = evt.target.result
    if (result.length > 0) {
      var parts = result.split(',')
      var dataBsf = parts[parts.length - 1];
      console.log(dataBsf);
      //call method to pass the base 64 here. 
    }
  }
};
```

```html
<body>
  <input id="fup" type="file" multiple="multiple" onchange="fileRunner.run(this)" />
</body>
```

I did not include a server side component to this because I think that should be agnostic and slightly out of scope here.

I am only logging the output to the console, but you would take the output and pump it to the web service.

Additionally, I referenced the input element in the event handler for the onchange using "this" because I had no idea how you wanted to handle it. Allowing the passing of an element provided a bit of loose assumptions on my part.

Comment: give me a few and I can put something together.

Comment: Did that work for you? If so, could you mark this answered or post a reply with issues? Thanks.